# I need to fetched data include to array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, apexcharts

```
let valArray = [];

connection.query(
  `SELECT COUNT(productId) AS NumberOfProducts , productId FROM cart GROUP BY productId ORDER BY productId DESC LIMIT 12  `,
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw console.log(err);
    if (res) {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        valArray.push(res[i].NumberOfProducts);
      }
    }
  }
);





var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 360,
      type: "bar",
      stacked: !0,
      toolbar: { show: !1 },
      zoom: { enabled: !0 },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: { horizontal: !1, columnWidth: "15%", endingShape: "rounded" },
    },
    dataLabels: { enabled: !1 },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Series A",
        data: valArray,
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
      ],
    },
    colors: ["#556ee6", "#f1b44c", "#34c38f"],
    legend: { position: "bottom" },
    fill: { opacity: 1 },
  },
```

First I need to fetched data storing in above assigned array . I tried out above way , it works but can not assign in to **series** data object. may be my approach wrong that's why it does not work.  please someone help me. I just want to assign fetched data in to above array then it need to call form  **series** data object.

Comment: It looks like confusion about async. If the callback is working, it is probably running after you test `options.data` for the result. Please edit to show the context where you discover the unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically what dhan said.

Here is an example.

```
// Wrap the collection of data in a function that returns a promise. This way you prevent unnecessary nesting.
const fillValArray = (connection, valArray = []) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  connection.query(
    `SELECT COUNT(productId) AS NumberOfProducts , productId FROM cart GROUP BY productId ORDER BY productId DESC LIMIT 12  `,
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (res) {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          valArray.push(res[i].NumberOfProducts);
        }
        resolve(valArray)
      }
    }
  );

});

// Create an async function to run the code, since await can only be used in an async function currently
const run = async () => {

  // Wait for the async process to complete the request for data.
  const valArray = await fillValArray(connection);

  // Create the desired object.
  const options = {
    chart: {
      height: 360,
      type: "bar",
      stacked: !0,
      toolbar: { show: !1 },
      zoom: { enabled: !0 },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: { horizontal: !1, columnWidth: "15%", endingShape: "rounded" },
    },
    dataLabels: { enabled: !1 },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Series A",
        data: valArray,
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
      ],
    },
    colors: ["#556ee6", "#f1b44c", "#34c38f"],
    legend: { position: "bottom" },
    fill: { opacity: 1 },
  }

  // log the desired object.
  console.log(options);

}

// Run the code
run();
```